# How to change the color of a line of text in quill.js?

Tags: javascript, quill

I have an editor like this

```
var container = document.getElementById('editor');
var quill = new Quill(container);
quill.setText('Hello\nWorld!\n');
```

Im trying to change the color of the first line to blue.
When I use the formatLine method like this

```
quill.formatLine(0, 1, {
    color: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)'
});
```

Nothing happens

When I change it to formatText I see a color change (only a single character though)

```
quill.formatText(0, 1, {
    color: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)'
});
```

Im guessing that color changes fall under `inline formatting` and are ignored

```
Formats all lines in given range, returning a Delta representing the change. See formats for a list of available formats. Has no effect when called with inline formats.
```

Does anyone know how I would change the color of a specific line? Is it possible to get the start and end character indices of a specific line?

Comment: It looks like quill is an object, try `quill = quill.formatLine(0, 1, {
    color: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)'
}); `

Comment: No, the issue is that color changes don't apply in formatLine calls. So I need some way to get the start and end character positions of a line so that I can call formatText instead.